# Using two separate string types in a list

Tags: c#

Ok so for my C# programming class I am making an adventure game. I think I understand how to do most of it expect I'm having trouble setting up the "world".

I have a class for the world (`World.cs`) where I started creating a list for each room.  However I'm confused of to add a name and description for each room.

For example if the `List` (room) is type `String` I would do `room.Add("Prison", "This is a prison)`.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's when you create a class

```
public class Room {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And hold a list of rooms:

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
```

In order to add anything to the list, simply do this:

```
rooms.Add(new Room { Name = "Prison", Description = "This is a prison" });
```

Objects are used to group data together, this will allow for much cleaner code. It is one of the keystones of Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: Ohhhhh I was missing the object part, awesome.
So it would be the same thing to create a list for items that would be in the rooms right?

Comment: @user3064291: yes. Create a class `Item` that holds their properties. Some people might advise you to use a `struct` instead since it's just holding a few fields for now. While correct, I think it would be best if you'd stay with just classes for now. Just as a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could do is to create a class indeed.

```
public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a list of `Rooms`

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
```

To add objects

```
Room room = new Room { Name = "", Description = "" };
rooms.Add(room);
```

---

From this point forward I will talk about things that exist, but that are not necessarily the best thing to do.

### [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

You can create an extension method such this one

```
public static class ListRoomExtender
{
    public static void Add(this List<Room> rooms, string name, string description)
    {
        rooms.Add(new Room { Name = name, Description = description });
    }
}
```

As I've specified, this method will only exist for lists of rooms. So if I have

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
```

I can use

```
rooms.Add("Room name", "Room description");
```

### Other types of "lists"

- [`StringDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  - You can't store more information if needed, only a pair of strings.
  - You don't have semantics, you access data through properties `Key` and `Value`.
  - You can't add two items with the same key.
- [`List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  - You can't store more information if needed, only a pair of strings.
  - You don't have semantics, you access data through properties `Key` and `Value`.